# How to insert this values into the database properly?

Tags: python

I have a file name log.txt

It's structure it's kind of like this:

```
2022-04-28 22:33:02,290\\INFO\\Database connection established
2022-04-28 22:33:07,470\\INFO\\Files concatenation
2022-04-28 22:33:09,708\\INFO\\Table xxx_xxx created
```

I want to send this to a database I have previously made a connection to.

```
with open("test.log",'r') as data_file:
    values = [line.split("\\") for line in data_file]
    engine.execute('INSERT INTO control (log_date, debugType, messa) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)', values)
```

When I print the values that will be passed to the database it shows up like this:

```
[['2022-04-28 22:33:02,290', '', 'INFO', '', 'Database connection established\n'], ['2022-04-28 22:33:07,470', '', 'DEBUG', '', 'Files concatenation\n'], ['2022-04-28 22:33:09,708', '', 'DEBUG', '', 'Table xxx_xxx created\n'], ...]
```

First of all, I want to exclude the value that comes after the comma after the timestamp (e.g. on the first line: `'2022-04-28 22:33:02,290'`, I want to take the `,290` out.

I also want to get rid of the empty strings where the \\ was.

Can you help me?

Comment: As a tip - learn how to break your problem down into the smallest chunks. For example, if you had a for loop instead of list comprehension, it would be very easy to strip out that 290. Start with the very basics and improve/optimise later once you get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file seems to have additional characters inside of it that is why you are getting these empty strings.
Naive and greedy solution:

```
final_list = []
with open("test.log",'r') as data_file:
    for line in data_file:
       line_list = line.rstrip('\n').split("\\")
       line_list[0] = line_list[0][:-4]
       final_list = list(filter(lambda l: l != '', line_list)) 
       final_list.append(final_line)
```

If you have list present (you completed reading and parsing into list) you could appply the same things:

1. To remove `''` just do filter on each list

```
final_list = [ list(filter(lambda l: l != '', inside_l)) for inside_l in whole_list]
```

2. to remove last three elements from a string just do `string[:-4]`
   so iterate over whole list and get first element and apply slicing

```
for inside_list in final_list:
    inside_list[0] = inside_list[0][:-4]
```

Comment: Hi. The first solution worked as a charm :)
But I couldn't get the second to work

Comment: I edited my answer try to read it now